# Open folder as project with CLion

Tags: intellij-idea, project, clion

Hey so I will be learning C Language and will be using CLion from Jetbrains. I have already used their IntelliJ IDEA IDE for Java. With IntelliJ, there is an option during the install to add a dialogue to the system so you can open folders as projects in IntelliJ. Is it possible to do the same thing with CLion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in CLion you need to check the Add “Open Folder as Project” option during the installation process:

[image]

Comment: Ah okay, previously installed CLion via the toolbox and it didnt give me the option

Comment: Is it possible to get this option (opening folder as Clion project) after Clion has been installed on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Even if the question is already older, there is a way to add a subsequent entry. This works also when installed via Toolbox.

Here's an example using CLion Nova:

1. Open the Registry (`Win + R` and then type `regedit`)
2. Navigate to: `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell`
3. Create a key: `CLionNova` (or another name)
4. Create a key: `command`
5. In CLionNova Key, set the value of (Default) to: `Open Folder as CLion Nova Project`
6. Add another string with the name `Icon.`
7. Set the value for `Icon` to the path of the tool executable or the icon file. E.g. `C:\_Entwicklung\Jetbrains\CLion Nova\bin\clion.ico`
8. In the `command` subkey, set the path to the executable with the argument '%V,' for example, `"C:\_Entwicklung\Jetbrains\CLion Nova\bin\clion64.exe" "%V"`
9. Repeat steps 2 to 8 in: `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell` and replace command `%V` with `%1`

Now the entry should be available.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]